# Angular - Prevent Internet Explorer cache on FormControl

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, form-control

I'm facing a problem with using FormControl on Internet Explorer and I haven't found a plausible solution at the moment. I have an input component where it is rendered with a value passed by a FormControl. The problem is that, for example, if I delete the content of the input on the screen and refresh the page, the component is rendered without the content, the value passed to formControl at the moment where the component is instantiated is ignored.

I know that if I refresh the page by pressing Ctrl + f5 works as expected, but how i prevent the Internet Explorer cache behavior?

Here is a minimal, reproducible example:

**My input component**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-component',
  template: ` <input type="text" [formControl]="inputControl" autocomplete="off"/> `,
})
export class InputComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() inputControl: AbstractControl;
  
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**Component where my input component is being used**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-input-component [inputControl]="inputControl"></app-input-component>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  inputControl = new FormControl('21/09/1999');

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure from what you’re saying, but is this an auto-fill issue maybe?

Comment: I test a formControl with default value and can't reproduce the issue. Could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**? So that we can have a test and see how to help. We can't make it clear with only the above text description.

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, it's something like that. Even with autocomplete = "off", the behavior still continues.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks for the feedback. I just added a minimal reproducible example as requested.

Comment: I use your code to test but it works well in IE. When I delete the content then refresh the page, the component will still render with content: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPRlP.gif. I test in IE version 11.630.19041.0. Which version of IE are you using? Which version of Angular are you using? Besides, please also check other parts of your code to see if there might be other code will cause the issue.